# Fetch request not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, fetch, gatsby

I have a contact form with a fetch request to post (formspree contact form). While on desktop and in any browser it works just fine but as soon as I go mobile it doesn't..

The button of the form says 'Send', while submitting that value changes to 'Sending..' and after successful submission it says 'Message sent'. On mobile, after hitting the button it switches to 'Sending..' but then nothing else happens and also I don't receive the submission.

I tried debugging using ghostlab and all I get is:

```
formData.entries is not a function
```

I haven't found any solution by looking that up so was hoping someone here might have an idea..

Here is my code, note that if (typeof window !== `undefined`) and window.onload=function had to be added for anything to work at all since I am using gatsby js to build my site.

```
if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {

window.onload=function(){

  const sendButton = document.getElementById('send-button')

  const formDataToJson = formData => {
    const entries = formData.entries();
    const dataObj = Array.from(entries).reduce( (data, [key, value]) => {
      data[key] = value;
      if (key === 'email') {
        data._replyTo = value;
      }
      return data;
    }, {});
    return JSON.stringify(dataObj);
  };


  const postToFormspree = formData => fetch(`https://formspree.io/myemail@gmail.com`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formDataToJson(formData),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(r => r.json());

  document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    sendButton.value = 'Sending..';

    const formData = new FormData(this);

    postToFormspree(formData).then(response => {
        sendButton.value = 'Message sent!';
        myform.reset();

    });
  });

}
}
```

Comment: Look at the Browser Compatibility table at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: You could just write: `const dataObj = [...formData].reduce`

Answer (score 1):

After being pointed into the right direction by Barmar, I got it working by simply adding the formdata-polyfill npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/formdata-polyfill

and then inside my main.js I added

```
var WebFont = require('webfontloader');
```

like so:

```
if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {

window.onload=function(){

  require('formdata-polyfill')

.....
```

Deployed it and tested in chrome and FF on mobile and working fine so far

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) `FormData.entries` is available in Chrome 50+, Firefox 44+, and Opera. It's not supported in Edge or Safari, and it's unknown what versions of Internet Explorer support it.

Comment: Argh ok thank you guys. Any recommendations on the best workaround? Maybe there is a polyfill or I could detect if its mobile and in that case, show a form that does not use fetch? Would that make sense? I am quite new to all of this but those seem the only viable options or is there anything else?

Comment: you can use `fetch`, the problem is with `formDataToJson`.

Comment: Oh ok, any ideas on that? The way a formspree form normally works is to redirect to a thank you page after submission so I could still show that version on mobile right? But if I can avoid that then of course I will since there is not much of a point for it in mobile I feel :/

Comment: Google "polyfill for formdata.entries"